# based on angular js and javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div id="gridView"  ng-repeat="prd in sortedProduct">

     <a ng-click="getProductbyDept(prd)">{{prd.name}} </a>

</div>
```

from the above code i am getting department name links like this:

- fresh food
- bakery
- drinks

when i click on fresh food i am getting the products 
but after clicking on bakery, the products are getting displayed after the fresh food products but i want output in different way like

when i click on fresh food it should show the products
but after clicking on bakery the fresh food products should get disappeared and bakery products should appear similarly for rest

Can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: We will need more code to do that.  We don't know what your function `getProductbyDept` do and we don't know how your html show the products

Comment: Can you show us your `html` and related `js` code?

Comment: then you need to show us getProductbyDept(prd) and it's relevant code,